# How to reuse linear layout in android?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a layout which consists of a hierarchy like this:

```xml
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout <!-- vertical orientation --> >
        <LinearLayout <!-- horizontal orientation --> >
            <TextView/>
            <TextView/>  
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My problem is that I have about 8-9 innermost Linear Layouts,
all of them having the same design attributes.
The only difference among them is id of Linear Layout 
and text of both the text views.

So, is there a way that every time I add a horizontal Linear Layout,
only things I have to mention are the attributes not the same.
That is, I do not want to write the same design attributes again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use  tag , for reusing the same layout over and over again .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/app_bg"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<include layout="@layout/titlebar"
         android:id="@+id/linear1/>
<include layout="@layout/titlebar"
         android:id="@+id/linear2/>

...
```

Now you can access your different linear layout through their id and for the textView inside your common linear layout can also be accessed through the include id . say linear1.textView.setText="TDemo Text" . Set your text at run time . Hope this will solve your issue .for better idea , please go through this : 
https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

Comment: So I can set attributes of linear layout, but how will I set the attributes of inner text views

Comment: Suppose your textView id is android:id="@+id/textView" inside linear layout whose id is  linear1 , then in order to set text   get the the textView of respective include layout . say linear1.textView.setText = "Demo" and for another include linear layout you can use linear2.textView.setText = "Demo".

Comment: Ok, but how to set the text in xml file, not at runtime? Even at runtime, I have two TextViews, so how will I access them uniquely?

Comment: Both the textView will have different id . With the help of id you can access the view . And while using <include> i.e. when include any layout in another then you can set the text of the included layout at run time only .

Comment: In oder to set the text for another text view of linear1 , you can use the same way as linear1.textView2.setText("demo");   . Here linear1 is the include layout id, through this you can access all the components of  included layout .